# Android dumpsys activity output format

Tags: android, adb

After this command

```
adb shell dumpsys activity p | grep <package>
```

I get this output:

```
*APP* UID 10060 ProcessRecord{41941528 23873:com.example.testservicestate/u0a60}
dir=/data/app/com.example.testservicestate-1.apk publicDir=/data/app/com.example.testservicestate-1.apk data=/data/data/com.example.testservicestate
packageList={com.example.testservicestate}
  - ActivityRecord{42073a50 u0 com.example.testservicestate/.MainActivity t211}
Proc # 0: fore  F/A/T  trm: 0 23873:com.example.testservicestate/u0a60 (top-activity)
PID #23873: ProcessRecord{41941528 23873:com.example.testservicestate/u0a60}
```

Which is the meaning of those infos or where can I find the format for this command.
Especially Iḿ interested in those letters F/A/T . Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `grep <package>` just do `dumpsys activity processes <package>`. You will see the section names and the whole output would make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual you can find all the info in the Android [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#13529).

In this case `F/A/T` stands for the activity in question being a foreground activity (A) and its process being in `PROCESS_STATE_TOP` state (T) and belonging to the `THREAD_GROUP_DEFAULT` scheduling group (F)

Comment: May I get a link to the source code you say?(I guess Android xref) I don't really know how to search this trough sources.

Comment: most of the `dumpsys activity` code is in `java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java` and `java/com/android/server/am/ProcessList.java`